# Help proving two measure theory lemmas with confusing notation (in my book it's labeled "substitution" and "chain rule").

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Recently, while going through and proving the theorems in a book I found about probability theory (*Modern Probability Theory* by Olav Kallenberg), I found two lemmas that were pretty confusing. I posted the screenshots below:

[image: this one]

[image: this second one]

It's mostly the notation that I find confusing, for the first one, for example, I took the left hand side to mean $\mu(g \circ f)$, and the right hand side to mean $\mu((f^{-1}) \circ g)$. However, this doesn't make sense, the left hand side requires that $\mu$ is $Ω \to R$, but the left hand side requires that $\mu$ is $S \to R$. Could someone please help me clear up the notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book is called "[Foundations of Modern Probability](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387953137)".

By *definition* (check page 10)
$$
\mu f=\int f\,d\mu=\int f(\omega)\,\mu(d\omega).
$$

So on the left hand side of (4), you have
$$
\mu(g\circ f)=\int (g\circ f)(\omega)\,\mu(d\omega).
$$

On the other hand, $\mu\circ f^{-1}$ is a *measure* (check the bottom of page 9):
$$
(\mu\circ f^{-1})B=\mu(f^{-1}(B)), \quad B\in\mathcal{S}.
$$
So on the right hand side of (4), 
$$
\lambda g=\int g(\omega)\ \lambda(d\omega),\quad \lambda=\mu\circ f^{-1}.
$$